# bgcolor to the th of table with width 70% possible in a table

Tags: html, css

I want to give bgcolor to the th attribute  only with width 70%.
Header is like "Mega Event Offer". I want to give background color to that only. But it's width is big. SO it is exceeding the heading also.. Can we do it? I googled.. But no use..
 Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand the problem here, but given that you want to apply the background only behind the text and not on the entire th-element, I guess you could wrap the text in a `span`-element and apply the background-color to that instead of the entire `th`-element.

Something like this:

**Markup**

```
..
  <th>
     <span class="mega-event">Mega Event Offer</span>
  </th>
..
```

**CSS**

```
.mega-event {
   background-color: #888;
}
```

Comment: Hi Eliasson, It is working fine.. But only to the text.. I want the bit height also to cover the color...

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary A span is an inline element, so it doesn't have width or height. If you want to give the element a height, you will have to make it a block element first. Try this instead `display: block; height: 15px;`